# Clarification regarding claim that the class Safe is exception safe

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, assignment-operator

You'll find on page 937 of [this document](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf) the following code:

```
template<class T> class Safe
{
    T* p;  // p points to a T allocated using new
    public:
    Safe() : p(new T) {}
    ~Safe() { delete p; }
    Safe& operator=(const Safe& a) { *p = *a.p; return *this; }
    // ...
};
```

It seems like, the object that was pointed by p will be leaked in the assignment operator above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There will be no leaks because he did not change the pointer. Of course, it's still missing the copy constructor, but beyond that, there is no error.

Comment: I'm giving you the credit for the answer, for this was the first I received.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a leak because he isn't CHANGING the pointer. If he did

```
Safe& operator=(const Safe& a) { p = a.p; return *this; }
```

Then it would be a memory leak. He's doing an assignment to the object pointed to by p, not to p itself.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is *not* a problem: It isn't the pointers being assigned but the pointed to values. Assuming `T`'s assignment is exception safe, `Safe<T>`'s copy assignment is safe, too. However, the class is missing the copy constructor.